# How to add a warning message if app is open and user want to uninstall it

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I created a bootstrapper EXE file which have .Net prerequisite and my MSI chained together. I am able to install/uninstall successfully using this EXE.

Now customer wants a condition where he should see a warning message if app is open and user trying to uninstall it. Is it possible to do this job with standardBootstrapper or I should write custom BA. I really dont know which condition and code I should write for this if custom is the only solution. Any lights in this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using standard bootstrapper the best way is to add custom action to your msi. [Just add property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668723/wix-toolset-how-to-set-a-property) (for example IsRunning='0' ), and change it using custom action when program is running.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CustomAction(Session session)
{
     if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
     {
        session["IsRunning"] = 1;
     }
     return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project) for more info about custom actions. And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi) uninstall custom action sample

Then add dialog to sequence that will be [shown depending on that property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652211/wix-how-to-warn-user-instead-of-terminating-installation-using-properties)

If you are using [custom bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840380/custom-wix-burn-bootstrapper-user-interface), you can just add that check to your code before your msi will be run, or before you'll show UI